# Few questions about key hash for Facebook SDK

Tags: android, ios, iphone, swift, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am developing an iOS app in swift and I am new to iOS but I have good knowledge of android. In Android we generally use:

```
public static void printHashKey(Context pContext) {
    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            String hashKey = new String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0));
            Log.i(TAG, "printHashKey() Hash Key: " + hashKey);
        }
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "printHashKey()", e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "printHashKey()", e);
    }
}
```

to generate a key hash but now I need key hash to register my iOS project on facebook development console. I have no idea how to do it. So I want understand:

- What is the role of key-hash. Is it like: In development mode if we make a build from our IDE and the machine key-hash is register on facebook then we can use facebook login else not. But from android code to generate key-hash it seems like package dependent(Uff!! lots of confusion).
- How to generate key hash for an iOS app?
- Can we use same key has for both iOS and android application?

Please share your thoughts and solution.